# String concatenation without spaces in Bash

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script to count the number of files in a directory, and then add a new file with name file<#files> to the end of the directory. My current attempt is:

```
name="out"
num=$(ls -l|wc -l)
echo foo > "${name}${num}"
```

However, this gives me a bunch of spaces, resulting in the filename `out      12`. Why do the spaces appear, and how do I concatenate these strings without creating spaces?

Comment: OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.5. Bash-3.2

Comment: Try `echo foo > "${name}${num## }"` ?  The idea here is to use bash's prefix removal to remove the spaces.  (There is a single space after `##`.)  If that doesn't work, try `echo foo > "${name}${num##$'\t'}"`

Comment: For the record, it works with bash 4.3.30 and coreutils 8.23 on Debian Jessie. I'd guess that your implementation of `wc` added spaces, but not sure.

Comment: No, wc is not adding spaces. If I try echo $num, I just get "12". But if I do echo "${num}", I get spaces and then 12

Comment: @Teofrostus this means `wc` added spaces, as `echo` without quotes strips whitespace.

Comment: When you do `echo $num`, the shell removes the spaces.  (This part of _word splitting_.)  When you do `echo "${num}"`, the shell keeps the spaces.  __That you see the spaces in the latter form means that  `wc` is adding spaces.__

Comment: @John1024: I think you meant `${num##* }` (which is the only way to get this to work with `##` (stripping of the longest prefix match, but is not generally robust, as it would strip _any_ chars. before the last space).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On **OS X (and BSD-like systems in general)**, **`wc -l` left-space-pads the number to 8 characters**, e.g., `_______7` (`_` representing a space here for technical reasons).

(If you use `wc`'s output *unquoted* with `echo` - e.g.,  `echo $(wc -l <<<'dummy')`, you will *not* see the padding, because the shell will "eat" the leading spaces; if you *double-quote* the command substitution, you'll see them:  `echo "$(wc -l <<<'dummy')"`

That said, **you're better off using neither `ls` nor `wc` - for both reasons of robustness and performance**; use *globbing* to capture all filenames in an array and use that *array's element count* instead:

```
name='out'
files=( * ) # collect all filenames in array

echo foo > "${name}${#files[@]}" # use array-element count
```

<sup>Note: By default, `*` will *not* include *hidden* items, just like the OP's `ls` command (because it doesn't include `-A` or `-a`).

Use `shopt -s dotglob` to include hidden items too.

Also, if there happen to be no matching items at all, Bash will return the pattern *as-is*, i.e., `*`; to have Bash return the *empty string* instead, use `shopt -s nullglob`.</sup>

---

**Generally**, if you do find yourself **needing to *trim leading and trailing whitespace* from command output and/or a Bash variable**:

- To **trim a value stored in a *Bash variable***, **use `read`**:

  ```
   # Single-line value:
   val='  a   b  '
   read -r val <<<"$val" # $val now contains 'a   b'

   # Multi-line value:
   # Note: Trims leading and trailing whitespace including newlines, but 
   # preserves *any* interior whitespace, including empty and all-whitespace lines.
   val=$'\n \t  one\n  \ntwo\n  \n'
   read -r -d '' val <<<"$val" # $val now contains $'one\n  \ntwo'
  ```
- To **trim *command output*** as part of a pipeline or **lines from *stdin* / a *file***:

  - If the value to trim has either ***no interior* whitespace *or* you want to ensure / don't mind that *interior whitespace is normalized* to a *single space* each**, pipe to **`xargs`** (this works, because `xargs`, after parsing the input into words, passes them to the `echo` utility by default - without shell involvement); the result is always a ***single* output line**; **caveat**: `xargs` removes embedded quotes and `\` instances, unless you `\`-escape them:

    ```
    val=$(ls | wc -l | xargs) # $val now contains trimmed count
    ```
  - **If preserving *line-interior* whitespace as-is matters**, use **`sed`**; note that - unlike `read -r d ''` above - this is **a LINE-based solution, so the number of input lines will be preserved**, including leading and trailing empty or all-whitespace lines, with **all-whitespace lines trimmed to *empty* ones** (assumes *GNU* Sed or *BSD* Sed):

    ```
    echo $'\nfoo \n \n bar \n' | sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$//g'
    # -> $'\nfoo\n\nbar'
    ```

---

- Simplified scenario: **Remove ALL whitespace** from a value, using **`tr`**:

  - **single-line / per-line**:

    ```
    tr -d '[:blank:]' <<<$'  a   b     c \n foo  ' # -> $'abc\nfoo\n'
    ```
  - **globally, including newlines**:

    ```
    tr -d '[:space:]' <<<$'  a   b     c \n foo  ' # -> 'abcfoo'
    ```

Answer (score 2):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004 describes how to concisely count the number of items in a directory. For example, the following code might do what you want:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
items=(*)
touch "file${#items[@]}"
echo "${#items[@]} items found, created new file: file${#items}"
```

Please note, however, that this count includes subdirectories and symlinks, not just files. In your description you asked for a count of files, though in your code example you seem to also want subdirectories and such. If you only want files, then the above example will have to be modified, perhaps with something like 'find . -type f'.

Comment: ++ for good advice in general (while the globbing + array-element count approach was already part of my answer, I didn't initially discuss `dotglob` and `nullglob`).
However, note the OP's focus is _trimming values_, not getting filesystem-item names - that part they seemed happy with (and that part - `ls -l` - implies: items of any type, excluding hidden items; with default Bash options in place, `*` returns the same set).
Also note that "files" is often used _loosely_ to refer to _all_ types of filesystem items - for lack of a *succinct* umbrella term.

Comment: Also note that `find . -type f` will find files in the entire _subtree_ of the current dir.; you need `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` to limit the results to files directly located in the current dir (and it's worth mentioning that the command will _invariably_ include hidden files, and that the output filenames will be prefixed with `./`, and not necessarily sorted).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/sh
name="out"
num=$(ls -l | wc -l | sed -e 's/ //g')
echo $num
```

which should strip out the beginning whitespace.

Comment: That works well in the case at hand, but it's worth pointing out that your `sed` command removes _all_ spaces; `sed 's/^ *//'` more specifically strips all _leading_ spaces.